# Is implementation of memoization in Haskell a monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, memoization

I tried to solve [Project Euler's Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) (involving length of a Collatz sequence) using memoization, and this is how I did to keep the results from previous calculations. I have this function, `collatzSequence`, that I want to memoized, and I memoize it with `computeWithMemo`, which takes a function, a value to calculate the function on, a `Map`, and returns the function's value at that point and an updated `Map`. Is this what a Monad pattern is? Thanks!

```
import Data.Map                                                                   

computeWithMemo :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Map Int Int -> (Maybe Int, (Map Int Int)
computeWithMemo fun key memo                                                      
  | elem key (Data.Map.keys memo) = (Data.Map.lookup key memo, memo)              
  | otherwise = (Just (fun key), Data.Map.insert key (fun key) memo)              

collatzSequence :: Int -> Int                                                     
collatzSequence x                                                                 
  | x == 1 = 1                                                                    
  | even x = 1 + collatzSequence (x `div` 2)                                      
  | odd x = 1 + collatzSequence (x*3 + 1)                                         

memoize f = computeWithMemo f                                                     

memoizedCollatz = memoize collatzSequence                                         

solve x m                                                                         
  | x > 1 = solve (x-1) (snd (computeWithMemo (collatzSequence) x m))             
  | otherwise = m                                                                 

solution = solve 10000 Data.Map.empty
```

Comment: Since memoization is stateful, using monadic binding looks like a reasonable way to represent its sequential nature; the same trick works for I/O. I wonder if `State` monad is directly applicable in your case: it's specifically built for passing the changes of state (memory) around.

Comment: so is this a monadic computation? I really have trouble understanding monads from tutorials but may be they are just this

Comment: Monads have a handy function `>>=` (aka 'bind' aka 'and then') which computes a function using the one monadic value and returning another: `foo >>= \x -> retrun bar`, cf. `foo().andThen(function(x) {return bar;})` in JS. So `>>=`s are easy to chain, and they are guaranteed to run in the order specified. This fact is used to implement imperative programming, which is especially apparent with `do`-notation. Monads are not _limited_ to this, though; they are just a pattern that emerges in many different circumstances (not a coincidence).

Comment: Note that checking for `key \`elem\` (Data.Map.keys memo)` and then using `Data.Map.lookup key memo` is an anti-pattern. Instead. you should do a `lookup` and then just pattern match on it -- you learn if `key` wasn't an element of the `Map` by `lookup` returning `Nothing`. Moreover, you are always returning `Just` a value in the first coordinate (either the `key` is in the `memo` and `lookup` returns `Just`, or it is not, and you return `Just (fun key)`); so the type of `computeMemo` is unnecessarily loose and should just reutrn an `(Int, Map Int Int)`.

Comment: Also, if `key` is not in the `memo`, you compute `fun key` twice. This may be optimized away by a sufficiently eager CSE optimizer, but you shouldn't rely on that here; just do something like `let result = fun key in (result, Map.insert key result memo)`

Answer (score 2):

It's an ad-hoc reimplementation of parts of the internals of the `State` monad in the sense that it creates and executes functions that takes and returns an additional argument in a way that simulates state.

The main differences between your code and `State` is:

- You hard-code the logic of passing around state for a certain type of function in your `solve` method.

  `State` provides a function `>>=` (bind) that defines how to combine two stateful functions, or how to call one stateful function from another (all monads are required to do this).
- You hard-code the process of creating a stateful function from a stateless one taking and returning an `Int`.

  `State` provides a function `return` that can be used to make any stateless function stateful (all monads are required to do this).
- You hard-code the operations you can do on your state, specifically memoizing functions in a `Map Int Int`.

  `State` provides some functions to [`get`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:get), [`set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:set) and [`modify`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:modify) the state that together with `>>=` can be used to create functions being stateful in all sorts of ways (this is specific to `State`, and not to monads in general).

So yes, you have basically defined a very, very specific and narrow case of one specific monad!

If you want to formally make it a true monad, you can define analogs to `>>=` and `return`, and perhaps even implement the [`Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) typeclass so you can use Haskell's combinators and syntactic sugar on them.